# Irreducible representation - Eigenvalues of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

I am currently working at Bruce Sagan's "The Symmetric Group". The following example is an illustration to show that Maschke's Theorem is not true for infinite groups. The following paragraphs are copied from the book:

---

Consider the matrix representation of $G = \mathbb{R}^{+}$

$X(r) = \begin{pmatrix}1&\log r\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, where $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

The subspace

$W = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}c\\0\end{pmatrix}: c \in \mathbb{C} \right\} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$

is invariant under the action of $G$.

Thus if $X$ is completely reducible, then $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ must decompose as the direct sum of $W$ and another one-dimensional submodule. By the matrix version of Maschke's theorem, there exists a fixed matrix $T$ such that

\begin{equation}TX(r)T^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}x(r)&0\\0&y(r)\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}

for all $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Thus $x(r)$ and $y(r)$ must be the eigenvalues of $X(r)$, which are both 1. But then

\begin{equation}X(r) = T^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}T = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}

for all $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, which is absurd.

---

The beginning is quite straightforward. The part that I do not understand is: "*Thus $x(r)$ and $y(r)$ must be the eigenvalues of $X(r)$.*"
Why do they have to be eigenvalues?

If you would like to have a look at the book, go to page 17 and 18 at

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Jm-HBaMdt8sC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So clearly, $x(r)$ and $y(r)$ are eigenvalues of $S = TX(r)T^{-1}$, so there is a vector $v$ such that
$$
Sv = x(r)v.
$$
So
$$
X(r)(T^{-1}v) = x(r)(T^{-1}v).
$$
Hence $x(r)$ is an eigenvalue for $X(r)$. Do likewise for $y(r)$.